# Can't start mongo with docker command, but can with /bin/bash inside container (with data volume)

Tags: mongodb, macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

This `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  database:
    image: mongo:3.2
    ports:
      - "27017"
    command: "mongod --dbpath=/usr/database"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/usr/database

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

results in this error (snipped):

```
database_1  | 2016-11-28T06:30:29.864+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /usr/database/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

Ditto for just trying to run the command in a container using that image directly:

```
$ docker run -v /usr/database mongo:3.2 mongod --dbpath=/usr/database
```

But, if I run `/bin/bash` when starting the container, and THEN start `mongo`, we're OK:

```
$ docker run -it -v /usr/database mongo:3.2 /bin/bash
root@8aab722fad89:/# mongod --dbpath=/usr/database
```

Based on the output, the difference seems to be that in the second scenario, the command is run as root.

So, my questions are:

1. Why does the `/bin/bash` method work, when the others do not?
2. How can I replicate that reason, in the docker-compose?

Note: On OSX, since that seems to effect whether you can mount a host directory as a volume for Mongo to use - not that I'm doing that.

Comment: So, this doesn't answer my questions, but does solve my underlying problem: `docker run -v db:/data/db mongo:3.2`

Comment: What does your `Dockerfile` for image `mongo:3.2` contain? If in the end of the file it uses `ENTRYPOINT` `mongod`, then you are doubling the docker start command.

Comment: `mongo:3.2` is an official Mongo image. I didn't make it. https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

Comment: Have you tried a `command: "/bin/bash -c  'mongod --dbpath=/usr/database'"` in your docker-compose or somehthing like that ?

Comment: Not with the interior ticks - that's probably what I was missing. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, this image  [hub.docker.com/_/mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) is an official MongoDB docker image from DockerHub, but NOT an official docker image from MongoDB.

Now to answer your questions,

> Why does the `/bin/bash` method work, when the others do not?

This answer is based on [Dockerfile v3.2](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile). First to point out that your volume mount command `-v /usr/database` , is essentially creating a directory in the container with the root ownership permission.

Your command below failed with `permission denied` because the the docker image is running the command as user `mongodb` (see [this dockerfile line](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile#L4)) . As the directory `/usr/database` is owned by `root`.

```
$ docker run -v /usr/database mongo:3.2 mongod --dbpath=/usr/database
```

While if you execute below `/bin/bash` then manually run `mongod`:

```
$ docker run -it -v /usr/database mongo:3.2 /bin/bash
```

Your are logged in as `root` and executing `mongod` as `root`, and it has the permission to create database files in `/usr/database/`.

Also, if you're executing the line below, it works because you're pointing to a directory `/data/db` which the permission has been corrected for user `mongodb` (see [this dockerfile line](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile#L60))

```
$ docker run -v db:/data/db mongo:3.2
```

> How can I replicate that reason, in the docker-compose?

The easiest solution is to use `command: "mongod --dbpath=/data/db"` because the permission ownership has been corrected in the Dockerfile.

If you are intending to use a host volume, you probably would have to add `mongodb` user on your host OSX and change appropriate directories permission. Modifying the permission ownership of a volume mount is outside the scope of [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Comment: Okay, I think that's my (fantastic, thank you) answer. To clarify, if I wanted to use a location other than `/data/db` inside the image, I'd need to make an image where that other location had the correct permissions?

Comment: Correct, if you wanted to use a location inside of the image (internal) other than `/data/db` you need to modify permission for `mongodb` user. if you wanted to use a location external to the image (i.e. host volume), you need to add a user `mongodb` on your host, then map the permission (guid) so that your container's `mongodb` user is able to use that external volume.